# Can I access FormData which is attached to an external POST request in my front end Javascript code? (SagePay)

Tags: javascript, request, form-data, opayo

Using SagePay, I send the user off to a separate page for them to complete their 3D Secure check if it's required.

[image]

I require a `PaRes` to be returned from SagePay so I can complete the next steps.

I provide a term URL for the user to return to once they have completed their 3DS check. This URL is just the page the user was previously on (for the sake of testing) ie my local `/make-payment` route.

When the navigation completes for this term URL, I can see the `PaRes` in the `FormData` of the request:

[image]

How can I access this FormData `PaRes` value?

It is not accessible on the browser's `FormData` object after being instantiated or anywhere else that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

After 3DSecure, these are sent back to your provided TermURL using a HTTP POST request. The form data can only be accessed on the server and not in the client side.

For example for a PHP backend, you can use the $_POST array to obtain the values and complete the processing with the final request.